# What does Operating System Environments (OSEs) mean on System Center 2012 Licensing?

Tags: windows, licensing, system-center

I was looking into [System Center 2010 Licensing Details](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/1/11128EC7-2BE7-480C-9D46-4ECECA9E481A/System%20Center%202012%20Licensing%20Datasheet.pdf) and came across with this term:

> # of Managed **Operating System Environments (OSEs)** per license

Do they mean regular Operating Systems? or adding "Environments" mean something else (platform, architecture, etc.)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From the context, we can see that it simply means each unique installation of Windows Server, whether physical or virtual.